# Insert / Update 50 Millions records in SQL Server fastest way

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert and update 50 Million into a table using Store procedure from staging table to base table. But the process is taking much much longer than expected approx 5-6 hours.

I tried implementing few indexes for performance tuning but none of them are working on the first time.

Any suggestion on how to handle and do the large data insertion.

Our SSIS program dumps data from CSV dumps inside the staging table and then our store procedure run in the end, the below insertion is causing time delay,

Code snippet - Staging to base table insertion

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Entries] (
        [TransactionID]
        ,[TimekID]
        ,[ResourceID]
        ,[INVOICE_DATE]
        ,[INVOICE_NUMBER]
        ,[CLIENT_ID]
        ,[LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID]
        ,[INVOICE_TOTAL]
        ,[BILLING_START_DATE]
        ,[BILLING_END_DATE]
        ,[INVOICE_DESCRIPTION]
        ,[ITEM_NUMBER]
        ,[EXP_FEE_INV_ADJ_TYPE]
        ,[ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS]
        ,[ITEM_ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT]
        ,[ITEM_TOTAL]
        ,[ITEM_DATE]
        ,[ITEM_TimeK_CODE]
        ,[ITEM_EXPENSE_CODE]
        ,[ITEM_ACTIVITY_CODE]
        ,[TIMEKEEPER_ID]
        ,[ITEM_DESCRIPTION]
        ,[LAW_FIRM_ID]
        ,[ITEM_UNIT_COST]
        ,[TIMEKEEPER_NAME]
        ,[TIMEKEEPER_CLASSIFICATION]
        ,[CLIENT_MATTER_ID]
        ,[TIMEKEEPER_EMAIL]
        ,[CreatedBy]
        ,[CreatedOn]
        ,[ModifiedBy]
        ,[ModifiedOn]
        ,[DeletedFlag]
        ,[sid]
        ,[ITEM_BASE_NUMBER_OF_UNITS]
        ,[ITEM_BASE_TOTAL]
        ,[UNIQUE_ID]
        ,[IsCancelled]
        ,[ENTRY_CLOSED_DATE]
        )
    SELECT ts.TransactionID
        ,(
            SELECT t1.ID
            FROM [dbo].[time] t1
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[TimekMaster] tm ON t1.ABATimekCode = tm.ID
                AND (
                    tm.Code = ts.ITEM_TimeK_CODE
                    OR tm.NAME = ts.ITEM_TimeK_CODE
                    )
            WHERE t1.sid = @SID
                AND t1.DeletedFlag = 0
                AND m.id = t1.matterid
            ) ID
        ,(
            SELECT r.[ID]
            FROM [dbo].[Resource] r
            WHERE r.[FirmUserID] = ts.[TIMEKEEPER_ID]
                AND r.[sid] = @SID
                AND r.[DeletedFlag] = 0
            ) ResourceID
        ,ts.INVOICE_DATE
        ,ts.INVOICE_NUMBER
        ,ts.CLIENT_ID
        ,ts.LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID
        ,REPLACE(ts.INVOICE_TOTAL, ',', '')
        ,ts.BILLING_START_DATE
        ,ts.BILLING_END_DATE
        ,ts.INVOICE_DESCRIPTION
        ,ts.ITEM_NUMBER
        ,ts.EXP_FEE_INV_ADJ_TYPE
        ,REPLACE(ts.ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS, ',', '')
        ,REPLACE(ts.ITEM_ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT, ',', '')
        ,REPLACE(ts.ITEM_TOTAL, ',', '')
        ,ts.[ITEM_DATE] --ITEM_DATE, varchar(1000),>
        ,ts.ITEM_TimeK_CODE
        ,ts.ITEM_EXPENSE_CODE
        ,ts.ITEM_ACTIVITY_CODE
        ,ts.TIMEKEEPER_ID
        ,CAST(ts.ITEM_DESCRIPTION AS VARCHAR(4000))
        ,ts.LAW_FIRM_ID
        ,REPLACE(ts.ITEM_UNIT_COST, ',', '')
        ,ts.TIMEKEEPER_NAME
        ,ts.TIMEKEEPER_CLASSIFICATION
        ,ts.CLIENT_MATTER_ID
        ,ts.TIMEKEEPER_EMAIL
        ,0 --<CreatedBy, int,>
        ,GETDATE() --<CreatedOn, datetime2(7),>
        ,NULL --<ModifiedBy, int,>
        ,NULL --<ModifiedOn, datetime2(7),>
        ,0 --<DeletedFlag, bit,>
        ,@SID --<sid, int,>
        ,REPLACE(ts.[ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS_BASE], ',', '') 
        ,REPLACE(ts.[ITEM_BASE_TOTAL], ',', '') 
        ,ts.[UNIQUE_ITEM_NUMBER] --<UNIQUE_DOCKET_ID, varchar(1000),>
        ,0 --ts.[ITEM_CANCEL] --<IsCancelled, bit,>
        ,ts.[ENTRY_CLOSED_DATE] --<ENTRY_CLOSED_DATE, varchar(100),>)
    FROM E_Staging ts
    INNER JOIN matter m ON m.firmmatternumber = ts.LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID
        AND m.[sid] = @SID
        AND m.[DeletedFlag] = 0
    WHERE 1 = (
            SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM [dbo].[Time] t1
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[TimekMaster] tm ON t1.ABATimekCode = tm.ID
                AND (
                    tm.Code = ts.ITEM_TimeK_CODE
                    OR tm.NAME = ts.ITEM_TimeK_CODE
                    )
            WHERE t1.sid = @SID
                AND t1.DeletedFlag = 0
                AND m.id = t1.matterid
            )
        AND ts.[Sid] = @SID
        AND ts.[TransactionID] = @TxnID
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [dbo].[Entries] te
            WHERE te.[sid] = @SID
                AND te.[DeletedFlag] = 0
                AND ts.[UNIQUE_ITEM_NUMBER] = te.[UNIQUE_ID]
            )
```

BASE Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Entries] (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
    ,[TransactionID] INT NOT NULL
    ,[TaskID] INT NULL
    ,[ResourceID] INT NULL
    ,[INVOICE_DATE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[INVOICE_NUMBER] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[CLIENT_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[INVOICE_TOTAL] NUMERIC(14, 2) NULL
    ,[BILLING_START_DATE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[BILLING_END_DATE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[INVOICE_DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_NUMBER] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[EXP_FEE_INV_ADJ_TYPE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS] NUMERIC(14, 2) NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT] NUMERIC(14, 2) NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_TOTAL] NUMERIC(14, 2) NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_DATE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_TASK_CODE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_EXPENSE_CODE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_ACTIVITY_CODE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[TIMEKEEPER_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(4000) NULL
    ,[LAW_FIRM_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_UNIT_COST] NUMERIC(14, 2) NULL
    ,[TIMEKEEPER_NAME] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[TIMEKEEPER_CLASSIFICATION] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[CLIENT_MATTER_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[TIMEKEEPER_EMAIL] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[CreatedBy] INT NULL
    ,[CreatedOn] DATETIME2(7) DEFAULT(sysutcdatetime()) NULL
    ,[ModifiedBy] INT NULL
    ,[ModifiedOn] DATETIME2(7) NULL
    ,[DeletedFlag] BIT DEFAULT((0)) NULL
    ,[sid] INT NOT NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_BASE_NUMBER_OF_UNITS] NUMERIC(14, 2) NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_BASE_TOTAL] NUMERIC(14, 2) NULL
    ,[UNIQUE_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IsCancelled] BIT DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[ENTRY_CLOSED_DATE] VARCHAR(100) NULL
    ,[MappingStatus] TINYINT DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[LINE_ITEM_PHASE_CODE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[Override] BIT DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[e_INVOICE_DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[e_CLIENT_ID] VARBINARY(8000) NULL
    ,[e_LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(8000) NULL
    ,[e_CLIENT_MATTER_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[AmountDocketed] NUMERIC(14, 2) DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[AmountBilled] NUMERIC(14, 2) DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[AmountWrittenDown] NUMERIC(14, 2) DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[AmountWrittenUp] NUMERIC(14, 2) DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[AmountWIP] NUMERIC(14, 2) DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[HourDocketed] NUMERIC(14, 2) DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[HourBilled] NUMERIC(14, 2) DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[HourWrittenDown] NUMERIC(14, 2) DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[HourWrittenUp] NUMERIC(14, 2) DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[HourWIP] NUMERIC(14, 2) DEFAULT((0)) NOT NULL
    ,[MappedBy] INT NULL DEFAULT((0))
    ,[MappedOn] DATETIME2 NULL DEFAULT(sysutcdatetime())
    ,[RemapBy] INT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_utb_entries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
    ,FOREIGN KEY ([TaskID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Task]([ID])
    ,FOREIGN KEY ([TaskID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Task]([ID])
    );
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Entries_TaskID] ON [dbo].[Entries] ([TaskID] ASC);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Entries_LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID] ON [dbo].[Entries] ([LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID] ASC);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Entries_UNIQUE_DOCKET_ID] ON [dbo].[Entries] ([UNIQUE_DOCKET_ID] ASC);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Entries_ResourceID] ON [dbo].[Entries] ([ResourceID] ASC);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Entries_INVOICE_NUMBER] ON [dbo].[Entries] ([INVOICE_NUMBER] ASC);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Entries_EXP_FEE_INV_ADJ_TYPE] ON [dbo].[Entries] ([EXP_FEE_INV_ADJ_TYPE] ASC);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Entries_IsCancelled] ON [dbo].[Entries] ([IsCancelled] ASC);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Entries_Grouped] ON [dbo].[Entries] (
    [TaskID] ASC
    ,[sid] ASC
    ,[DeletedFlag] ASC
    ,[ID] ASC
    ) INCLUDE (
    [INVOICE_NUMBER]
    ,[LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_TOTAL]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_BASE_NUMBER_OF_UNITS]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_BASE_TOTAL]
    ,[IsCancelled]
    )
    WITH (
            SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
            ,DROP_EXISTING = OFF
            ,ONLINE = OFF
            ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Entries_Grouped1] ON [dbo].[Entries] (
    [sid] ASC
    ,[DeletedFlag] ASC
    ,[IsCancelled] ASC
    ) INCLUDE (
    [ID]
    ,[LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID]
    ,[EXP_FEE_INV_ADJ_TYPE]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_BASE_NUMBER_OF_UNITS]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_BASE_TOTAL]
    )
    WITH (
            SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
            ,DROP_EXISTING = OFF
            ,ONLINE = OFF
            ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Entries_Grouped2] ON [dbo].[Entries] (
    [sid] ASC
    ,[DeletedFlag] ASC
    ,[ID] ASC
    ,[LINE_ITEM_BASE_TOTAL] ASC
    ,[TaskID] ASC
    ) INCLUDE ([LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID])
    WITH (
            SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
            ,DROP_EXISTING = OFF
            ,ONLINE = OFF
            ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Entries_Grouped3] ON [dbo].[Entries] (
    [TaskID] ASC
    ,[sid] ASC
    ,[DeletedFlag] ASC
    ,[ID] ASC
    ,[ResourceID] ASC
    ) INCLUDE (
    [INVOICE_NUMBER]
    ,[EXP_FEE_INV_ADJ_TYPE]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_TOTAL]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_DATE]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_BASE_NUMBER_OF_UNITS]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_BASE_TOTAL]
    ,[IsCancelled]
    ,[ENTRY_CLOSED_DATE]
    )
    WITH (
            SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
            ,DROP_EXISTING = OFF
            ,ONLINE = OFF
            ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Entries_Grouped4] ON [dbo].[Entries] (
    [TaskID] ASC
    ,[sid] ASC
    ,[IsCancelled] ASC
    ,[DeletedFlag] ASC
    ,[ID] ASC
    ,[ResourceID] ASC
    ) INCLUDE (
    [INVOICE_NUMBER]
    ,[EXP_FEE_INV_ADJ_TYPE]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_TOTAL]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_DATE]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_BASE_NUMBER_OF_UNITS]
    ,[LINE_ITEM_BASE_TOTAL]
    ,[ENTRY_CLOSED_DATE]
    )
    WITH (
            SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
            ,DROP_EXISTING = OFF
            ,ONLINE = OFF
            ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Entries_LINE_ITEM_DATE] ON [dbo].[Entries] ([LINE_ITEM_DATE])
GO

CREATE STATISTICS [Stat_Entries_1] ON [dbo].[Entries] (
    [IsCancelled]
    ,[ID]
    ,[TaskID]
    ,[sid]
    )
GO
```

staging table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[E_Staging] (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
    ,[INVOICE_DAE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[INVOICE_NUMBER] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[CLIENT_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[LAW_FIRM_MATER_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[INVOICE_TOTAL] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[BILLING_START_DAE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[BILLING_END_DAE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[INVOICE_DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(8000) NULL
    ,[IEM_NUMBER] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[EXP_FEE_INV_ADJ_TYPE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS_BASE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_TOTAL] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_BASE_TOTAL] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_DAE] VARCHAR(100) NULL
    ,[IEM_TASK_CODE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_EXPENSE_CODE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_ACTIVITY_CODE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[TIMEKEEPER_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(8000) NULL
    ,[LAW_FIRM_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_UNIT_COST] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[TIMEKEEPER_NAME] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[TIMEKEEPER_CLASSIFICATION] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[CLIENT_MATER_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[TIMEKEEPER_EMAIL] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[UNIQUE_ITEM_NUMBER] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_CANCEL] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[Sid] INT NULL
    ,[TransactionID] INT NULL
    ,[ValidationStatus] VARCHAR(20) NULL
    ,[ValidationMessage] VARCHAR(200) NULL
    ,[UploadStatus] VARCHAR(20) NULL
    ,[StatusMessage] VARCHAR(50) NULL
    ,[CREATEdOn] DAETIME NULL DEFAULT(sysutcdaEtime())
    ,[FirmLastModifiedon] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[ENTRY_CLOSED_DAE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[UNIQUE_Docket_ID2] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[DockeEd_Released_Billed] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[IEM_PHASE_CODE] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[WriE_Down] VARCHAR(200) NULL
    ,[e_ClientId] VARBINARY(MAX) NULL
    ,[e_INVOICE_DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,[e_IEM_DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(8000) NULL
    ,[e_CLIENT_MATER_ID] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_E_Staging] PRIMARY KEY CLUSERED([ID] ASC)
    );
GO

CREATE NONCLUSERED INDEX [nci_wi_E_Staging_2150E36DEE003CE53D44FC548A4CD6CC] ON [dbo].[E_Staging] (
    [Sid] ASC
    ,[TransactionID] ASC
    )
GO

CREATE NONCLUSERED INDEX IX_E_Staging_CREATEDON ON [dbo].[E_Staging] (CREATEDON)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSERED INDEX IX_E_Staging_LAW_FIRM_MATER_ID ON [dbo].[E_Staging] (LAW_FIRM_MATER_ID)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSERED INDEX IX_E_Staging_UNIQUE_IEM_NUMBER ON [dbo].[E_Staging] (UNIQUE_IEM_NUMBER)
GO
```

Comment: this depends to many factors. are both databases on same machine? are locations different? what is the link speed? can you truncate and insert? what is your query look like?

Comment: Could add some code, to see how it looks? Hard to came up with something "in dark"

Comment: Add some code, give us information about your environment. In other words put light on our road :)

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest that instead of creating new indexes on target table, ideally you should be disabling indexes before insertion.

1. Disable indexes and constraints on the target table.
2. Insert the records.
3. Enable indexes and constraints.

This should give you better performance for insertion.

Apart from this, you need to optimize your select query. You can get more help if you share the select query also.

Comment: specific answer to very broad question!!

Comment: Even Primary key indexes?

Answer (score 5):

Better than using stored procedures, I would recommend you to use the SQL Server import assistant:

- On the database, right click + Import
- Select the database, then select the table
- Selecting the table, can click it and click on "Enable Mappings"
- Click on "Delete rows in destination table" if you want to remove previous data
- Very important "Enable identity insert" to allow to copy the IDENTITY columns across the databases
- Follow with the default options to the end of the Wizard

From my experience, this is in general by far much quicker than using specific manual solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do this its a weekly process to import and update the records.

Comment: Yes, you can. When the wizard finishes it allows you to save as an SSIS package what you can save into the Server and then schedule as a Job.